# Dataweave filtering nested arrays and displaying in descending order

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I'm trying to filter an array based on some values nested in objects.

My data pertains to offers (array), customers(array) with tickets(array) and other child arrays.
I want to orderBy to get all the customers information ordered by the latest timeStamp (attribute in tickets array)

From the example, offer 1 has customer 50001 with tickets 1001, 1002 and customer 50002 with tickets 1003, 1004. I want the customer which has latest timestamp in all the tickets available to be displayed first: (Desc order) with all the other passengers ordered accordingly.

**Request Payload:**

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "offers": [{
        "offerInfo": {
            "orderNumber": "1",
            "orderCreationDtTime": "2023-01-10 00:00:00"
        },
        "customers": [{
                "customerInfo": {
                    "name": {
                        "frstNm": "JOHN",
                        "lstNm": "DOE"
                    }
                },
                "customerNum": "50001",
                "tickets": [{
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-07 00:38:00.167000",
                        "ticketService": {
                            "ticketNum": "1001",
                            "ticketType": "3"
                        },
                        "ticketReps": [{
                                "seq": "1",
                                "comment": "1st",
                                "location": "US"
                            },
                            {
                                "seq": "2",
                                "comment": "2nd",
                                "location": "US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-11 00:38:00.167000",
                        "ticketService": {
                            "ticketNum": "1002",
                            "ticketType": "3"
                        },
                        "ticketReps": [{
                                "seq": "3",
                                "comment": "1st",
                                "location": "US"
                            },
                            {
                                "seq": "4",
                                "comment": "2nd",
                                "location": "US"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "customerInfo": {
                    "name": {
                        "frstNm": "FAN",
                        "lstNm": "SING"
                    }
                },
                "customerNum": "50002",
                "tickets": [{
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-10 00:38:00.167000",
                        "ticketService": {
                            "ticketNum": "1003",
                            "ticketType": "3"
                        },
                        "ticketReps": [{
                                "seq": "1",
                                "comment": "1st",
                                "location": "US"
                            },
                            {
                                "seq": "2",
                                "comment": "2nd",
                                "location": "US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-19 00:38:00.167000",
                        "ticketService": {
                            "ticketNum": "1004",
                            "ticketType": "3"
                        },
                        "ticketReps": [{
                                "seq": "1",
                                "comment": "1st",
                                "location": "US"
                            },
                            {
                                "seq": "2",
                                "comment": "2nd",
                                "location": "US"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

**Expecting Payload after transform message:**

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "offers": [{
        "offerInfo": {
            "orderNumber": "1",
            "orderCreationDtTime": "2023-01-10 00:00:00"
        },
        "customers": [{
                "customerInfo": {
                    "name": {
                        "frstNm": "FAN",
                        "lstNm": "SING"
                    }
                },
                "customerNum": "50002",
                "tickets": [{
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-19 00:38:00.167000",
                        "ticketService": {
                            "ticketNum": "1004",
                            "ticketType": "3"
                        },
                        "ticketReps": [{
                                "seq": "1",
                                "comment": "1st",
                                "location": "US"
                            },
                            {
                                "seq": "2",
                                "comment": "2nd",
                                "location": "US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-10 00:38:00.167000",
                        "ticketService": {
                            "ticketNum": "1003",
                            "ticketType": "3"
                        },
                        "ticketReps": [{
                                "seq": "1",
                                "comment": "1st",
                                "location": "US"
                            },
                            {
                                "seq": "2",
                                "comment": "2nd",
                                "location": "US"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "customerInfo": {
                    "name": {
                        "frstNm": "JOHN",
                        "lstNm": "DOE"
                    }
                },
                "customerNum": "50001",
                "tickets": [{
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-11 00:38:00.167000",
                        "ticketService": {
                            "ticketNum": "1002",
                            "ticketType": "3"
                        },
                        "ticketReps": [{
                                "seq": "3",
                                "comment": "1st",
                                "location": "US"
                            },
                            {
                                "seq": "4",
                                "comment": "2nd",
                                "location": "US"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "timestamp": "2023-01-07 00:38:00.167000",
                        "ticketService": {
                            "ticketNum": "1001",
                            "ticketType": "3"
                        },
                        "ticketReps": [{
                                "seq": "1",
                                "comment": "1st",
                                "location": "US"
                            },
                            {
                                "seq": "2",
                                "comment": "2nd",
                                "location": "US"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script will help you.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::util::Values
---
 payload update ["offers","customers"] with (
    (($ map (
        $  update {
                case .tickets ->  ($ orderBy $.timestamp  as LocalDateTime {format : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"}) [-1 to 0]
        }
    )) orderBy $.tickets[0].timestamp as LocalDateTime {format : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"}) [-1 to 0]
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the update operator for each step and auxiliary functions for clarity.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun convertTimestampToNumber(t)=t as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"} as String {format: "yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSSSS"} as Number
fun getMaxTimestamp(t)=max(t map convertTimestampToNumber($.timestamp))
---
payload update {
    case offers at .offers -> 
        offers map ($ update {
            case customers at .customers ->    
                customers map ($ update {
                    case tickets at .tickets ->  tickets orderBy ( -convertTimestampToNumber($.timestamp) )
                })
                orderBy ( -getMaxTimestamp($.tickets) )
            }
        )
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "count": 1,
  "offers": [
    {
      "offerInfo": {
        "orderNumber": "1",
        "orderCreationDtTime": "2023-01-10 00:00:00"
      },
      "customers": [
        {
          "customerInfo": {
            "name": {
              "frstNm": "FAN",
              "lstNm": "SING"
            }
          },
          "customerNum": "50002",
          "tickets": [
            {
              "timestamp": "2023-01-19 00:38:00.167000",
              "ticketService": {
                "ticketNum": "1004",
                "ticketType": "3"
              },
              "ticketReps": [
                {
                  "seq": "1",
                  "comment": "1st",
                  "location": "US"
                },
                {
                  "seq": "2",
                  "comment": "2nd",
                  "location": "US"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "timestamp": "2023-01-10 00:38:00.167000",
              "ticketService": {
                "ticketNum": "1003",
                "ticketType": "3"
              },
              "ticketReps": [
                {
                  "seq": "1",
                  "comment": "1st",
                  "location": "US"
                },
                {
                  "seq": "2",
                  "comment": "2nd",
                  "location": "US"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "customerInfo": {
            "name": {
              "frstNm": "JOHN",
              "lstNm": "DOE"
            }
          },
          "customerNum": "50001",
          "tickets": [
            {
              "timestamp": "2023-01-11 00:38:00.167000",
              "ticketService": {
                "ticketNum": "1002",
                "ticketType": "3"
              },
              "ticketReps": [
                {
                  "seq": "3",
                  "comment": "1st",
                  "location": "US"
                },
                {
                  "seq": "4",
                  "comment": "2nd",
                  "location": "US"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "timestamp": "2023-01-07 00:38:00.167000",
              "ticketService": {
                "ticketNum": "1001",
                "ticketType": "3"
              },
              "ticketReps": [
                {
                  "seq": "1",
                  "comment": "1st",
                  "location": "US"
                },
                {
                  "seq": "2",
                  "comment": "2nd",
                  "location": "US"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```